# AKS Hybrid setup

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have 1 master node & 2 worker nodes in the on-premise servers i.e. bare metal running kubernetes.

Considering that after few months, we might need more nodes. We will be using Azure going further for provisioning more nodes.

Can AKS work in combination with the on-prem machines, such that active master is in on-prem & the second master is in Azure, and the additional worker nodes can be scaled up/down in Azure?

Is it possible to achieve the below scenario, where on-prem & azure both can work together for the same K8s cluster? If yes, then any 3rd party tool is available for setting up as so and make life easy?

### On-Premises

1 master & 2 worker nodes

+

### AKS

1 master & 5 worker nodes (scale up/down)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found options for you to consider:

1. [Running Kubernetes in a hybrid environment](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/hybrid-environment.md#running-kubernetes-in-a-hybrid-environment):

> Setting up Kubernetes to work in an hybrid cloud environment is
> absolutely possible today and many companies choose this path as a
> progressive migration to Azure. You can benefit from the flexibility
> and scalability of Azure, maintain existing systems running on your
> local network, and get them to talk to eachother seamlessly. This
> however still requires a non-negligible investment in the
> infrastructure setup, and maintenance of it.

2. [Azure Arc hybrid management and deployment for Kubernetes clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/arc-hybrid-kubernetes):

> You can use Azure Arc to register Kubernetes clusters hosted outside
> of Microsoft Azure, and use Azure tools to manage these clusters
> alongside clusters hosted in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

The later one would require you to use [Azure Arc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/).

I haven't used them myself but they seem to fit your use case.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor for your guidance. I will move further with your suggestion.

Comment: I am still exploring...Azure Arc seems a good choice, but then Azure Stack HCI is also available.

Comment: This is not the answer for the question. The AKS hybrid environment does not approach a cluster spanning a hybrid cloud network, but rather how a cluster running in AKS can connect to on-prem network

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, today you can use the AKS engine to setup nodes on-prem only if you're using Azure Stack Hub which is an extension of Azure that can run workloads in an on-premises environment by providing Azure services in your datacenter.
Azure Arc can bring together two clusters but they won't operate as they were single cluster.